# Vault cassandra Config

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to mount Cassandra Database as a secret backend for Vault. I am using latest version of cassandra 3.11. when i run the command

vault write database/config/cassandra plugin_name=cassandra-database-plugin  allowed_roles="readonly" hosts=localhost username=cassandra password=cassandra

I get the error below * error creating database object: error verifying connection: error creating session: gocql: unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial hosts: dial tcp [::1]:9042: getsockopt: connection refused

I read some post related to this issue - https://github.com/gocql/gocql/issues/713. But, how do i rectify this as I am using vault and not cql directly. Thanks.

Comment: Message at valult server console - 2017/09/25 20:59:52 gocql: unable to dial control conn ::1: dial tcp [::1]:9042: getsockopt: connection refused 2017/09/25 21:14:01 gocql: unable to dial control conn ::1: dial tcp [::1]:9042: getsockopt: connection refused

Comment: can you provide output of `netstat -anp | grep 9042`

Comment: i am using windows what may be the equivalent command